# What is the importance of small angle approximation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, approximation, limits-without-lhopital

I have seen many approximations like

$$\tan x \approx x$$

$$\sin x \approx x$$

$$\cos x \approx 1-\dfrac{x^2}{2}$$

$$\dfrac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)\tan(x)} \approx \dfrac{x^2}{4} + x^{-2} - 1 $$

These are for smaller values of $x$ or theta, but what is the need to take this approximation into consideration?

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: They are useful sometimes, for example when mathematically modeling a pendulum. The small angle approximation simplifies the differential equation that describes the motion of the pendulum. The simplified equation has a nice analytical solution.

Comment: In the past, small-angle approximations were frequently used in computer math libraries to provide accurate results for small arguments **fast**. Examples can be seen in FDLIBM from the 1990s (code from FDLIBM has been re-used by many projects to the present day): [cosine](https://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/k_cos.c), [sine](https://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/k_sin.c), [tangent](https://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/k_tan.c). With the adoption of SIMD and GPU computing, modern math library code often tries to minimize branches and use of small-angle approximations has therefore fallen out of favor.

Answer (score 1):

They are useful in limit situations.

Mathematically, they are the Taylor polynomials of order 2 centered at zero. The Taylor polynomial $T_{x_0,k}$ of order k of a function $f \in C^k(a,b)$ and centered at $x_0 \in (a,b)$ is the polynomial of degree at most k that best approximates the function $f$ near the point $x_0$; in particular it satisfies the condition (that also determines its form, try to think about it):
$$
T_{x_0,k}^{(j)}(x_0)=f^{(j)}(x_0) \quad j=0,1, \dots k
$$
where $g^{(j)}(x_0)$ denotes the j-th derivative of $g$ at $x_0$ (the zero derivative is the function itself).
So the explicit form of the Taylor polynomial is:
$$
T_{x_0,k}(x)= \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!}f^{(j)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^k
= f(x_0)+f’(x-x_0)+\frac{1}{2}f’’(x_0)(x-x_0)^2+ \dots + \frac{1}{k!}f^{(k)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^k
$$
Try to compute the derivatives of the sine, cosine, tangent functions and you’ll see that those polynomials are indeed what you called approximations for small angles.

It’s important to underline that these polynomials are not equal to a function, but (using the same notation) $f(x)-T_{x_0,k}(x)=o((x-x_0)^k)$ is a little-o of $(x-x_0)^k$, that is:
$$
\lim _{x \to x_0}\frac{f(x)-T_{x_0,k}(x)}{(x-x_0)^k}=0
$$

Now you can choose to approximate a function with its Taylor polynomial where you are in a limit situation. A classical example is when you’re studying the small oscillation of a pendulum, but here ‘small’ depends on your misurations.

You can find a lot more about Taylor polynomials here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1):

For an illustration, suppose that you want to solve for $x$ the equation
$$\sin (x)+\cos (x)+\tan (x)=\frac 32$$ Using the tangent half-angle substitution, the problem will be to find the root of
$$5 t^4-4 t^2+8 t-1=0$$ which is feasible with radicals but which will be a nightmare.

Using the approximations, the *approximate* solution is given by the root of
$$x^2-4 x+1=0\quad \implies \quad x=2-\sqrt 3=0.267949$$ while the exact solution is $0.265909$  (that is to say a relative error of $0.77$%)